# How bad is react for SEO? how bad is it the generate urls in the backend (in terms of SEO)?

Tags: reactjs, seo, next.js, server-side-rendering, google-crawlers

I developed an application using React js.
This application requests the server URLs on the fly because the URLs are generated according to logic done by the user.

SEO is very important for this application, and I know that Google doesn't crawl React very well. Is it true? What if I can provide an XML site map, wouldn't it help?

Is it necessary for me to migrate the application to using SSR or Next.js? Is it very complicated, assuming that the app is almost fully developed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Take half an hour to go through the [get started tutorials of Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app?utm_source=next-site&utm_medium=homepage-cta&utm_campaign=next-website) and you can tell if it is complicated or not for yourself.